# Has Google IID Server been deprecated?

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging, instanceid

Google provides an instance ID server ([Google Server Documentation](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server)) whereby an instance ID can be passed and the server will return information about that specific instance of an application including the package name, version, platform, etc.
It appears that this API service still returns this information if it is passed the new Firebase Installation ID (or the Firebase Installation ID derived from the FCM token).
The documentation link above does not note that this API service has been deprecated although the Instance ID service has been flagged as deprecated and replaced with the Firebase Installation ID.

Is this service still supported?

Comment: From reading the doc you linked and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/package-summary) it sounds like the service is deprecated, but not yet retired (as far as I can tell). Why are you asking though? Do you have a problem with existing apps that already use Instance ID? If so, can you edit your question to show that problem?

Comment: My apps have been updated to use the FCM token which includes the new Firebase Installation ID.  I have a backend server that receives requests from the app along with its Firebase Installation ID over an https connection.  The backend server then validates that the request is from a valid application installation using the IID server API call and then creates a custom firebase auth token that is returned over https to the app so that it can sign-in to the firebase database.  I don't want users to have to create accounts and login but want to control access to the database.